# android youtube download url 403 forbidden

Tags: android, youtube, download

there are some videos that can't download.

I got download url by using this

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=itGNQbJwRSk
```

Is there anyone why below url is not available to download?

total url:

```
http://r1---sn-a5m7lnek.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1391267516&ms=au&source=youtube&sver=3&upn=OzZzFV_-2o4&id=8ad18d41b2704529&itag=22&mt=1391243224&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&fexp=935622%2C914924%2C926515%2C916623%2C936910%2C936913&sparams=gcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mv=m&ip=183.101.166.55&key=yt5&gcr=kr&signature=F303D0C863C27A6A46124A09E40F308BB67181E013.3FA3E17460DDF6ECA004D9E48B1356849534EBFFFF
```

separated url with each params:

```
http://r1---sn-a5m7lnek.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?

expire=1391267516&

ms=au&

source=youtube&

sver=3&

upn=OzZzFV_-2o4&

id=8ad18d41b2704529&

itag=22&

mt=1391243224&

ipbits=0&

ratebypass=yes&

fexp=935622%2C914924%2C926515%2C916623%2C936910%2C936913&

sparams=gcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&

mv=m&

ip=183.101.166.55&

key=yt5&

gcr=kr&

signature=F303D0C863C27A6A46124A09E40F308BB67181E013.3FA3E17460DDF6ECA004D9E48B1356849534EBFFFF
```

and I used below codes in open stream

```
    u = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();//to know the size of video
    huc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36");
    huc.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.setDoOutput(false);
    int size = huc.getContentLength();      
    int status = huc.getResponseCode();
    Log.e("download", status+ huc.getResponseMessage());
    is = new BufferedInputStream(huc.getInputStream());
```

but it returns status = 403, size = -1.
I couldn't find anything to help yet.

Is there anyone have a idea?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240011/get-the-download-url-for-youtube-video-android-java

Comment: @Haresh I'm using that :) before starting download

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This video is using cipher signature. As you can see in the info returned by http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=itGNQbJwRSk, it has

```
'use_cipher_signature=True'
```

To download this type of video, first you have to decode its signature. Decoding algorithm is present in the player file (HTML5player or Flash player).

After decoding you have to use the same IP address to download the video from where you have fetched all the information. (You can bypass same IP restriction using Proxy)

It's better to scrape the webpage of that particular video and search for `;ytplayer.config = {(.*?)};` . This contains all the required information.

If you don't want to scrape then you can use below method to get the JSON object:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<Video-ID>&spf=prefetch
```

Please check this API for easy solution: [CipherAPI](http://api.gitnol.com/).

Another cool API: [YTstream API](http://ytapi.gitnol.com).

Comment: Also, I am able to download it by my method :)

Comment: Do I have to change ip address of parsed element to android's ip address?

Comment: Yes. But did you decoded the cipher signature. If not then it will still throw 403 error. Also same IP address restriction can be bypassed by using a proxy.

Comment: yes, I decoded the signature using "&sig=" or "&s=" but I still get 403 error. Can you give me some reference site of bypassing Ip restriction?

Comment: Tubget is first downloading the file on their server and then providing it to its users

Comment: Are you sending the same cookies, using the same user-agent header, sending the request from the same IP address, and sending the request shortly after extraction? All these are or were required at some point.

Comment: thank you for reply. I think my problem came from same IP address restriction. so, your opinion is that I have to make proxy server. right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47202/discussion-between-yountae-kang-and-akhilesh)

Comment: @Akhilesh could your share your solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. I am able to extract `ytplayer.config` by parsing the watch page. Also, I am using the same machine/IP address for both type of transfer. However, I want to use the code which doesn't rely on external service (such as CipherAPI) etc. Can I get the detail of how to extract the decrypt routine?

Answer (score 4):

**In short:** https://github.com/lure/YoutubeGrabber

**Long story:**
Every youtube video page contains a js block which initialise html5 player. Of course, there is aa flash player, too, but JS one is more easily to understand.

Streams located in two params: `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` for video+audio combined and `adaptive_fmts` for video or audio separate streams. Each link is made up from two let's call it parts:

1. everything what is going before `url=https:` and
2. everything from this point till the `,` (comma) which separates streams.

What you should know about initialising block is: some params may appear twice and you have to keep only one copy in your request. You can't predict which params may be dropped out so try to include everything you've found in a "raw" link. Special part of all of this is a signature that is required by backends. Beware, that signature may appear in a first or second part of link.

There is 3 types of signatures in a current time:

- `signature` - this one is plain and need no decipher, requires no handling.
- `sig` - ciphered
- `s` - ciphered

Having this blocks, player should prepare each link and request backend for stream chosen. It's done by concatenating all existing params excluding duplicates and append prepared signature.

While you can carefully find all possible player version this likely is not the best solution. It seems better to download player from your application and extract the exact decoding function from it. This approach will work with ANY youtube video page.

Despite of your decision, you still need the function. Most of the time this function may be found with this RegEx

```
set\("signature",\s*(?:([^(]*).*)\);
```

Use any formatting tool to read it source. You'll find that the main function uses one addition so you should extract it too. After that it's quite easy to implement the function in java or (which I prefer better) to extract decipher function and keep it around.

Steps in short: 
 1. extract `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` and `adaptive_fmts`
 2. split by `,`
 3. find decipher function in player and reimplement it in language of your choice or extract and `eval`.

for example, here is a function extracted from http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-new-en_US-vflhlPTtB/html5player-new.js

```
var fs = {
    Q2: function (a, b) {
        a.splice(0, b)
    }, cK: function (a) {
        a.reverse()
    }, yy: function (a, b) {
        var c = a[0];
        a[0] = a[b % a.length];
        a[b] = c
    }
};
function gs(a) {
    a = a.split("");
    fs.yy(a, 40);
    fs.Q2(a, 3);
    fs.yy(a, 53);
    fs.yy(a, 11);
    fs.Q2(a, 3);
    fs.cK(a, 8);
    fs.Q2(a, 3);
    fs.yy(a, 16);
    fs.cK(a, 75);
    return a.join("")
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to extract `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` and `adaptive_fmts` and also being able to find key value pairs within them. I can see some streams have key 'signature' and some have 's'. I need help to identify where can I find the decrypt routing. I have got base.js file and it has so many functions. So I am not sure if gs() and fs() is the final function list - or do we have to find some pattern from it. Also, what do I apply gs() on? is this like `signature = gs(s.value)` ?

Comment: > where can I find the decrypt routing.
In the youtube player itself. I've specified, that signatures are decoded in a player. gs and fs are obfuscated names. 
You can try to call `signature = gs(s.value)` it should work for some videos. If not, your best shot is to extract the appropriate function from javascript code and run it in JVM. 

Please, examine: https://github.com/lure/YoutubeGrabber/blob/master/src/main/scala/ru/shubert/yt/YouTubeQuery.scala, the `def registerPlayer` function.

Answer (score 1):

I also Search on Same kind of stuff and find few useful links , on some videos they  are not so good but hope after debug or see the code you may easily understand how they workd

What us Understand :

1-These code Download watch Url from link which is basicaly metadata of video
2-Parse that file according to format( video URL , Quality ) 
3-Decrypt Urls

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/323771/YouTube-Downloader-Using-Csharp-NET
https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

Comment: I'm already extract download url. like this
http://r13---sn-nx57ynl7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?fexp=924614%2C914027%2C916623%2C937417%2C924616%2C913434%2C936910%2C936913&ms=au&itag=18&mt=1392030059&ipbits=0&gcr=kr&ip=119.195.148.8&upn=61rd_crGr2E&mv=m&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&sparams=gcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&id=c2aedfb4e641cb41&expire=1392055439&key=yt5&sver=3&signature=D39576EBC5AC55CE15E1B9B4213EB582F1AC73CC.F917F39BA98DB22D900296A096DA4FD86E57C9C5C4C4 but It returns 403 error when I download file from this.

Answer (score 0):

I write a python script to download youtube video: https://github.com/wayne931121/youtube_downloader

There is one thing to attention. When you get the decrypt function in base.js, that's not mean you get the currect decrypt function, because in different youtube video may have different base.js url. Yesterday I think I successfully get the decrypt function in base.js, but it keep 403 forbidden and 403 forbidden and 403 forbidden... . I don't know why until today I find the decrypt function in base.js is different than yesterday, the yestrday I got var function Rwa(){...}, but today I got var function Qwa(a){a.split("");...} in base.js . Lucky, the real decrypt function is not much different than yesterday, it only change name, rearrange the real decrypt function in Rwa(a){a.split("")...}, and replace the arguments that the real decrypt function will use (int). **And when I use the currect decrypt function, it successfully get the video for me.** And I finnally know why youtube.dl use regex to catch decrypt function in base.js instead of direct let javascript decrypt function transform to python function.

It seems youtube change base.js url once a day.

When you want to find the decrypt function in base.js, the key words are: split(""),  encodeURIComponent, decodeURIComponent, signature, sig.

You can also see the details in:

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L1403

Here are some base.js url I got.

Format:

Windows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/${Js_Id}/player_ias.vflset/${Country}/base.js
```

Android:

```
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/${Js_Id}/player-plasma-ias-tablet-${Country}/base.js
```

Some url I catched: (2022/10/${day})

https://www.youtube.com/s/player/4bbf8bdb/player_ias.vflset/zh_TW/base.js
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/24c6f8bd/player_ias.vflset/zh_TW/base.js
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/64588dad/player_ias.vflset/zh_TW/base.js
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/4bbf8bdb/player-plasma-ias-tablet-zh_TW.vflset/base.js
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/24c6f8bd/player-plasma-ias-tablet-zh_TW.vflset/base.js
https://www.youtube.com/s/player/64588dad/player-plasma-ias-tablet-zh_TW.vflset/base.js

Something I finded in base.js:

```js
//From youtube base.js

//Yesterday I got
Rwa=function(a){a=a.split("");RB.ss(a,4);RB.jM(a,6);RB.jM(a,45);RB.e0(a,3);return a.join("")};
var RB={ss:function(a){a.reverse()},
jM:function(a,b){var c=a[0];a[0]=a[b%a.length];a[b%a.length]=c},
e0:function(a,b){a.splice(0,b)}};

//Today I got
Qwa=function(a){a=a.split("");PB.Co(a,14);PB.Co(a,14);PB.Zo(a,56);PB.GZ(a,2);return a.join("")};
var PB={Co:function(a,b){var c=a[0];a[0]=a[b%a.length];a[b%a.length]=c},
Zo:function(a){a.reverse()},
GZ:function(a,b){a.splice(0,b)}};

//Common
QE = function(a, b, c) {  //### This Function will decrypt signatureChiper ###//
    b = void 0 === b ? "" : b;
    c = void 0 === c ? "" : c;
    a = new g.SB(a,!0);
    a.set("alr", "yes");
    c && (c = Rwa(decodeURIComponent(c)), //### This Line will decrypt signatureChiper ###//
    a.set(b, encodeURIComponent(c)));
    return a
}

QE = function(a, b, c) {  //### This Function will decrypt signatureChiper ###//
    b = void 0 === b ? "" : b;
    c = void 0 === c ? "" : c;
    a = new g.SB(a,!0);
    a.set("alr", "yes");
    c && (c = Qwa(decodeURIComponent(c)), //### This Line will decrypt signatureChiper ###//
    a.set(b, encodeURIComponent(c)));
    return a
}

RE=function(a,b,c){b=void 0===b?"":b;c=void 0===c?"":c;a=new g.SB(a,!0);a.set("alr","yes");c&&(c=Rwa(decodeURIComponent(c)),a.set(b,encodeURIComponent(c)));return a};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't download video from youtube. It's illegal. You can only use the playback services.

> Section 4c You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

Comment: This site "http://tubget.com/" can download every youtube video.
What I want to know is How they do this.

Comment: I dont think you would get anything illegal from this site

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. This should be a comment.

Comment: Being against a website's ToS does *not* make it illegal.