# googlevideo link has 403 error with sever IP

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I'm going to get googlevideo links.

Now I'm using curl on php.

> My script is working only on Localhost because of current local ip .

Explaining this problem is so hard ,But the urls and ips are here :

online: https://mokhaatab.com/v/ , http://www.irxtra.com/v/ => **403** (problem)

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...&ip=domainip...
```

this site: http://api.getlinkdrive.com/ => **ok**

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...&ip=userip...
```

localhost => **ok**

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...&ip=userip...
```

What is `http://api.getlinkdrive.com/` doing to use user ip and there is no problem ?

What do you prefer ? (What is the best way?)

[image]

please help me.

Comment: what is the exact error message returned by the server and what is the exact request you are making to the api.

Comment: @DaImTo 403. That’s an error.

Comment: there are at least four different 403 errors. that is just the error code what is the full error message

Comment: https://mokhaatab.com/v/ you can see the error while run the link in my site

Comment: you do know that this is NOT google drive api nor is it an api.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496126/android-youtube-download-url-403-forbidden http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104702/youtube-dl-library-and-error-403-forbidden-when-using-generated-direct-link-by

Comment: @DaImTo the files are based on drive.google.com

Comment: Where are you getting the links then?  Drive.files.get? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get  this error is not coming from drive its coming from the link itself.

Comment: Thanks , but i didn't find any way following links

Comment: The thing is the file is probably private which means you cant just link it.  If its on your google drive as you say try and set it to public see what happens.   It looks like a permissions thing to me.   It can also be a location issue Google has some countries blocked

Comment: the links arfe public, and I have test it ok Germany server - http://www.irxtra.com/v/